# Store the database on any outside server of an android app

Tags: android, firebase

I have used Firebase to store my database. But I am getting errors in setting it up for the application.
I have created a new project in the website and then configured it by using the package name.I also downloaded the json file and then copied it to the Project folder. And I also made changes to the Build.gradle file and module based gradle file.

Build.gradle file is as follows:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle (module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hsports.bandpop"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.6.1'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I am getting the following errors on pressing sync button.

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/I324671/AndroidStudioProjects/BandPop/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>

Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.6.1
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/I324671/AndroidStudioProjects/BandPop/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: There is no "android class" for this. You're gonna have to build a server and do some synchronization between devices

Answer (score 1):

There is no Android class for this. Instead, you could build you own server/api to help you achieve it or you can use some third party services that help you easily sync/store your client data.
It's recommended to use [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) . It's easy to use and cross platform.

Comment: I have changed the question. I have configured the database using Firebase. And I am getting some errors while sync. Please help in this.